# How to make JAWS screen reader recognize and read content of cefsharp ChromiumWebBrowser control?

Tags: winforms, accessibility, cefsharp, jaws-screen-reader

I have winforms application that contains cefsharp ChromiumWebBrowser component. I want JAWS to read it's content. Now JAWS only read title of main window. Is there any way to achieve this? I tried "force-renderer-accessibility" flag but it didn't help me.

Here is the code i tried:

```
var settings = new CefSettings()
        {
            CefCommandLineArgs = { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("force-renderer-accessibility", "true") }
        };            
        Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: false, browserProcessHandler: null);
```

Comment: What was the problem of your code? Why did it not work?

Comment: By default the browser is run in a different message loop. Search the general usage guide for message loop for details

Answer (score 2):

Following amaitland's prompting above we found the following solution.

Disable MultiThreadedMessageLoop - you then need to periodically invoke DoMessageLoopWork as per the crude sample below.

```
        var settings = new CefSettings()
        {
          MultiThreadedMessageLoop = false
        };            
        Cef.Initialize(settings);

        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser ("https://url.com/");

        var t = new Timer {Interval = 5};
        t.Start();
        t.Tick += t_Tick;

        this.panel1.Controls.Add(browser);

    }

    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke((Action) (() => Cef.DoMessageLoopWork()));
    }
```

Comment: DoMessageLoopWork should be run roughly 60 times per second, which translates to around every 16ms. Running too frequently has unforseen consequences.

Comment: Ok that's great information thanks.  I wasn't sure about that.