# Chromium wrapped in WPF - find element and invoke action

Tags: c#, wpf, automation, chromium, cefsharp

ChromiumWebBrowser is wrapped inside WPF Windows app. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Wpf/ChromiumWebBrowser.cs

When I use Inspect tool for Windows I am not able to locate elements inside Chromium. Seems to be image without any name. Is it possible to invoke action in Chromium any way?

Comment: Please add comment when giving downrate. Feedback like this is not helpful for anyone.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an accessibility / `UIA` issue.

By default Chromium doesn't enable accessibility unless it detects a screen reader or other advanced use of the accessibility APIs.

With the standalone browser you can enable it manually by using the `--force-renderer-accessibility` command-line flag, or visit `chrome://accessibility` to enable it for one session.

For your issue with `CefSharp.Wpf ChromiumWebBrowser` things get more complicated, see these:

- [How to make JAWS screen reader recognize and read content of cefsharp ChromiumWebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42163764/how-to-make-jaws-screen-reader-recognize-and-read-content-of-cefsharp-chromiumwe)
- https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2053